# Posting images with Twitpic/Yfrog from a website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I want to have a button on my site that users can click to post an image on their twitter account using Twitpic/Yfrog.  I have been looking around for some sample code that can do this, but I have been unable to find anything.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search of "twitpic php" should give you a few examples, same for Yfrog. For example,

http://www.digimantra.com/technology/php/post-pictures-on-twitpic-api-using-php/

I'd also read their respective API documentations,

- http://twitpic.com/api.do
- http://code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/YFrogAPI